# Excel sum if meets condition

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I currently have two columns that look like this:

```
value | condition
   50 | Y
   60 | N
   30 | Y
   10 | Y
```

I cant seem to make use of IF function to get a sum of all the rows. Basically the aim here is to only sum the values if condition is Y and display the total in a cell. And if condition column is N, it will see value as 0. I want to be able to do this without the need of creating an additional column even though I understand this is easily done with a brand new column.

Comment: You mean [`SUMIF`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sumif-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b)?

Comment: Something like `=SUMIF(B2:B5,"Y",A2:A5)` will be what you want...

Comment: ahhh yes yes, thanks for that. I never knew this function existed. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as Nick mentioned, you can use Sumif:

```
     A   |    B
1  value | condition
2     50 | Y
3     60 | N
4     30 | Y
5     10 | Y
```

**sumif structure:**

```
=sumif(Range, Criteria, Sum_Range)
```

**sumif for table above:**

```
=sumif(B2:B5,"Y",A2:A5)
```

Excel formulas are not case-sensitive and there is no difference between A1:A5 and A2:A5 because the table titles are not important but start row and end row is important in both Range and Sum_Range.